# How to Insert Text into table cells using Google Docs API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-docs-api

I'm encountering an implementation problem I need some help with:

I am building a Google Docs integration that involves programmatically creating a table and then mapping through an array of records to add the data of those records to the table cells. I'm able to create a blank table and locate the start index of each cell to insert the data into, but when I try to use the `insertText` request from the docs and place the text in a specific cell I get the following error:

> "Invalid request[1].insertText: The insertion index must be inside the
> bounds of an existing paragraph. You can still create new paragraph by
> inserting new lines."

I've tried the following

1. Simply inserting my text and hoping that each insertText request places text in a new cell
2. Adding `'\n'` at the start index of the cells
3. Creating the table with tableRows already defined (this error
   out as an invalid request format)
4. Creating cells one-by-one and inserting text after each appended 1x1 column or row (eventually you create a row that duplicated the row above it with multiple columns and all text would just be in the first cell)
5. Inserting Column breaks after the first cells text in hopes it would shift the
   paragraph over to the new cell

Here's the last implementation I tried:

(For context I aim to filter through an items array, create a table for each item, and then for every subitem in that item object to have a table row where relevant data will go under Header 1, 2 and 3, but for now I'd be happy just to get the tables and headers in the right places)

```
var requests = []    
await Promise.all(
        items.map(async (item) => {
          let subitems = []
          subitems = item.subitems.filter((subitem) => subitem.selected)
    
          //Create table api call
          await docs.documents
            .batchUpdate({
              documentId: newDoc.data.documentId,
              resource: {
                requests: [
                  {
                    insertTable: {
                      columns: 3,
                      rows: item.subitems.length + 1,
                      endOfSegmentLocation: { segmentId: '' },
                    },
                  },
                ],
              },
            })
            .then((res) => res.data)
    
          //Api call for cell data
          var docData = await docs.documents
            .get({
              documentId: newDoc.data.documentId,
            })
            .then((res) => res.data)
    
          requests.push(
            {
              insertText: {
                text: 'Header 1',
                location: {
                  index:
                    docData.body.content[2].table.tableRows[0].tableCells[0]
                      .startIndex,
                },
              },
            },
            {
              insertText: {
                text: 'Header 2',
                location: {
                  index:
                    docData.body.content[2].table.tableRows[0].tableCells[1]
                      .startIndex,
                },
              },
            },
            {
              insertText: {
                text: 'Header 3',
                location: {
                  index:
                    docData.body.content[2].table.tableRows[0].tableCells[2]
                      .startIndex,
                },
              },
            }
          )
    
        })
      )
    
      //Insert Text API call
    
      var myDoc = await docs.documents
        .batchUpdate({
          documentId: newDoc.data.documentId,
          resource: {
            requests,
          },
        })
        .then((res) => res.data)
    
      return myDoc
    }
```

If you need any more info let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share a copy of your document? I can't repro this as-is